# Mold on bottom of fig tree

Tags: mold, figs

[image]

Bottom of fig tree with soft spongy mold
Can anybody tell me what this is at the bottom of my fig tree? It looks like it killed part of it? Any remedy or advice. Thanks

Comment: Are  you saying some of the tree or its trunk is now dead? Have you had lots of very wet weather in the last few weeks? Have you tried leaning or pushing against the trunks to see if they're still solid and stable,or wobbly and likely to fall?

Comment: We live in the South east, and it is alway humid here and has been raining on and off. The branch is wobbly and most definetely dead. However that mold is extending to other live branches and I am wondering whether the mold killed that branch of the tree and what can I do to save the rest of the tree...

Answer (score 1):

If the trunk is already dead and the fungus is spreading, it's most likely one of the foot and butt rots at the root. There is nothing you can do to save the rest of the tree, though removal of the dead trunk with the worst of the fungus might mean the rest lasts a bit longer. The fungus will be working its way up the inside of the tree as well as the outside, I'm afraid. It's probably safest to remove it altogether.